# I renamed an html template but django template loader keeps searching for the old file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pycharm

I'm a complete python/django noob.  I had an html template file called **book_detail.html**, and the app was running fine.  I renamed the file to **book_view.html** and i get an error.

I ran manage.py runserver but it doesn't seem to picking up the new name.

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: PycharmProjects/my_proj/my_proj/books/templates/books/book_detail.html (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: PycharmProjects/my_proj/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/books/book_detail.html (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: PycharmProjects/my_proj/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/books/book_detail.html (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: PycharmProjects/my_proj/my_proj/books/templates/books/book_detail.html (Source does not exist)
```

My question is, what is causing this, and is there a way for me to tell django/python to rebuild the project when there's a template name change?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't update the name you used in your view. Check the name of the template there.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.BookList.as_view(), name = 'book_list'),
    path('view/<int:pk>', views.BookView.as_view(), name = 'book_view'),
    path('new', views.BookCreate.as_view(), name = 'book_new'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>', views.BookUpdate.as_view(), name = 'book_edit'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', views.BookDelete.as_view(), name = 'book_delete'),
]

Comment: and this is my views.py

class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book

class BookView(DetailView):
    model = Book

class BookCreate(CreateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['name', 'pages']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('books:book_list')

class BookUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['name', 'pages']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('books:book_list')

class BookDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Book
    success_url = reverse_lazy('books:book_list')

Comment: my book_list.html has

    <td><a href="{% url 'books:book_view' book.id %}">view</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'books:book_edit' book.id %}">edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'books:book_delete' book.id %}">delete</a></td>

Comment: I don't see you defining which template to use anywhere. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/ Oh and please add the code you just wrote as real code to your original post. As code blocks.